"Riiiight," he said. What synonym of said can be used here?
This the excerpt:

“I can take him,” a man standing beside the entrance interrupted. Approaching them, he continued, “I can take him there, Uncle Graham, help him find a room.”
“What are you up to this time Logan?”
“Nothing. Just offering to help him find the place.”
“Right," the old man said.

Here, the old man stretched out the word right in a manner to convey that he doesn't believe him. Do I have to use "Riiiight" or is there a synonym of said or some adverb I can use here?
EDIT 1 :- So, after reading the answers and comments I feel like I should add some additional information. Firstly, just to be clear. there is a sarcastic element to the old man's tone, as in, he doesn't believe the man.
Second,  this scene is tight and I need to convey the not-believing-you part outside of conversation. I have written myself into a pinch here but the I can't edit the dialogue without changing entire chapter structure, or writing the dialogue in a way that misrepresents the characters. That's why I am hoping for some alternative of said or other phrase instead of "Right" that could get me out of this pinch.
Lastly, some details about the old man, and Logan. The old man, he a serious person. Even his sarcastic "Right" is sharp(Please read sharp with emphasis as I couldn't use italics or bold in comments), jaded, serious, weighted in a way that both options fail to express.
EDIT 2 :- Is the sarcastic-lack-of-belief of word "Right" clear in this sentence:

"Right; and nothing to do with what you heard earlier in the lobby?"

I will need to add a few extra(plot wise unnecessary) lines to the original dialogue; and it is a bit of a (small)compromise on the old man's character and his and Logan's dynamic; but I am realizing after reading the answers and comments that I don't have more convenient options.

If I was writing very casually, I might even use ""Right," he sarcasmed."  Verbing is fun!

@Exal: That is terrible advice! If I read that in a book, I would drop it in the bin, with a gentle sigh of disgust.

How about: "Sure you are," the old man said.

“Right," the old man sniggered. or snorted, sneered, etc, depending on character.

Given the clarifications and what you’ve said about the old man’s character, I would suggest The old man scoffed. “Right.” (or perhaps “Right,” the old man scoffed”, though I agree that finding synonyms for said is rarely the way to go).

If you're feeling adventurous: "sarcased" ?

"If you say so"

Drawled is one option, as it means "a slow way of speaking in which the vowel sounds are made longer and words are not separated clearly", though it does have a connotation of importunate advances*. Other options are to describe the lengthening of the vowel (e.g. drawn-out) or the intended connotation (e.g. sceptically). Linguists speak of "prolonged vowels". But that term will make your narration seem somewhat detached and analytical and your speaker might appear like he is being described as having a speech disorder.
You can repeat the i as you did: "Riiight." This is quite common today, especially in books for younger readers or those written in a less formal, more personal narrative style.
I cannot tell you what you want to write. You need to find a good thesaurus and dictionary to find all the synonyms and similar words. There are many online for free. You can also search Google Books for instances of that spelling and see how other authors describe it. E.g.:


"Riiight, then ...” the brigadier drawled.
"Riiight?" Brysen teased.
"Riiight?" He slapped the guy to his right with the back of his hand.
"Riiight?"¶ "Riiight," I drew out the word in a perfect imitation of how she had said it.
"Riiight," Vince says to Victor, "riiight," he says again with the same drawn-out inflection young people say right on, saying a prolonged yesss as if experiencing a sexual climax—Yesss, Yesss, Yesss—bragging to the world they're making it.
etc.



*  E.g. ' "See you later, baby" he drawled to her. Amarrah shivered at the thought of seeing him again ... ' or ' "Ready to honky-tonk, baby?" he drawled, voice husky with arousal. ' (examples from Google Books)

Drawled was my first impulse too.

Same ^ and I don't think it implies a drunkard (that would be "slurred") so much as, simply, an American :-)

Do I have to use "Riiiight" or is there a synonym of said or some adverb I can use here? In other words, you're promoting the idea that "'right,' he drawled" is contextually equivalent to "'riiight,' he said."  When I encounter the word "drawl" I think of Texans and the U.S. Bible Belt states. I don't think "drawled" leads me to "sarcastic."

@JBH I'm promoting no such thing, and I find nothing in OP's question or my answer regarding sarcasm. I'm saying that one can use riiight and recommend that OP should find the word that best conveys their intended meaning using a thesaurus and usage examples from literature. I merely gave some examples of what one might find, but since I don't know what OP wants to write, I cannot promote anything specific.

@Randal'Thor The focus of that part was on importunate, not drunkard. I have edited my answer.

To my ear the connotations of “importunate advances” are very slight.  If other things in the context set up some sort of lechery, then certainly drawled fits it well; but if there’s nothing else suggesting it, then one drawled certainly wouldn’t bring it to mind.  The much more salient connotations, to me, are various specific accents it’s associated with: Texas and the broader South (in the USA), leisured upper-class Brits, and Queensland and some other rural parts of Australia.

@Ben Just to clarify, there is a sarcastic element to the old man's tone.

@EMS Not necessarily. Besides sarcastic ("I think you are stupid"), his stance could also be sceptical ("I'm not sure I believe that"), questioning ("Are you sure?"), or surprised ("What?!"). OP only specificed disbelief.

@Ben What do you mean “not necessarily”? EMS is the OP, and the writer of the scene is telling you that the old man is being sarcastic. // I have to agree with others here that drawled doesn’t imply sarcasm at all to me; it just makes the old man feel Southern.

@EMS Ooops, sorry, wasn't aware that you are OP.

The correct synonym for "said" here is "said."
Please trust me on this.  The more you use words like "drawled", "growled", or, god forbid "ejaculated" (yes, I grew up reading old British children's novels), the more you draw attention to the framing of the dialogue instead of the dialogue itself.  "Said" gets out of the way.  The reader doesn't even notice it, and as a result the dialogue itself stands out much more brightly.
What you can absolutely get away with here is "Riiight" instead of "Right", just as you did in framing the question here.  Anything else about the character's tone should already be clear to the audience from the context (the rest of the dialogue, the character's established personalities, their body language, etc).
Read Hemingway's "Hills Like White Elephants" for a master-class on how little assistance good dialogue actually needs.

In his rules for writers, Elmore Leonard somewhat famously advised, er, said, not to use any synonyms for "said".  And also not to use an adverb with it, "...he admonished gravely."

The full dialogue uses very few synonyms of said, or said itself for that matter. But the this scene is tight and I need to convey the not-believing-you part outside of conversation. I know I have written myself into a pinch here but the I can't edit the dialogue without changing entire chapter structure, or writing the dialogue in a way that misrepresents the characters. That's why I am hoping for some alternative of said or other phrase instead of "Right" that could get me out of this pinch.

You can edit the dialog. You have just convinced yourself otherwise. Learning to edit is part of learning to write.

"Right. You expect me to believe that."  Unless you are writing verse, that insertion makes the sarcastic nature of the response pluperfectly obvious with, I expect, no other change required. "Said" wasn't the problem, "Riiight" was. Especially since you yourself said the extra i's were wrong.

I strongly agree with this. "Said" is often an invisible word. It is possible to overuse it, but it's hard. I can only think of one example of it being overused and that involved pages of almost pure dialog using short sentences to the point that almost every line contained "said". As long as you aren't in that situation, using "said" is almost always fine.

Or: "Right." "You don't sound convinced." "I'm not, but go on. Convince me." Which may suit your character better or may not. There are many alternatives available. Don't get hyper focused on one; consider the alternatives. And wherever possible, show, don't tell.

@DougWarren Thank you for jogging my memory. Yes, Leonard's advice is exactly where I first learned this lesson.  The only exceptions I allow myself are for when something truly goes beyond the level of speech, such as "snarled", "growled", or "yelled", and those I try to use sparingly.  What I learned from Hemingway is that more often you can simply leave out dialogue tags entirely. Unless it's really unclear who is speaking without them, don't use them at all.

@EMS You've convinced yourself that you need a dialogue tag here, but you really don't. Even without "riiight" instead of "right" the intent is perfectly clear. Trust the dialogue, and trust the reader.

@Peter Without the extra i’s and the dialogue tag, it’s absolutely not perfectly clear that it’s sarcastic – it can just as well be plain acceptance.

The desperate search for ways to say "said" without it becoming repetitive is sometimes referred to as "saidism". Really.
There is an entire class of jokes based on this pattern, known as "Swifties" in honor of the original Tom Swift books. Random bad example:

"I guess we'll have to replace the mitral valve," Tom said, halfheartedly.
"But wouldn't stopping his heart, you know, kill him?" Pete interrupted.

I suggest looking carefully at how some of your favorite authors handle this, and adopting/adapting some of their solutions. My own preference is to, as much as possible, structure the scene in such a way that it is obvious who is speaking...

A stranger approached them. "I couldn't help overheating. I'm Doctor Barnard."
Pete stared. "Not the famous heart surgeon?!"
"I'm afraid so. Quite the coincidence, I admit. You'd never believe it if you read it in a book."

There are other solutions. The easiest way to learn them is to pay attention when you're reading.
RWRWTATP. "Real writers rewrite to avoid the problem."

So, I should simply use "Riiight" then?

But "Riiight" really doesn't go along with the old man's personality; even "Drawled" doesn't go along with his personality. He a serious man. Even his sarcastic "Right" is sharp(Please read sharp with emphasis as I couldn't use italics or bold in comments), jaded, serious, weighted in a way that both options fail to express.

I can't write the book for you. I pointed out one approach. Applying it, if it is the right solution for your style, is something you need to do. If it isn't, that's fine too; as I said,read to see how other authors are solving the problem and pick something that does work.

Question: If it doesn't go with his personality, why are you writing it that way? Write what he would have said, as he would have said it.

I didn't realize the disparity until later so the the chapter and the whole dialogue is already finished, and its just one sentence, so I am going to leave it be if I cannot find a more suitable replacement sentence. Or an alternative phrase instead of "Riiight."

The advice to use an unadorned, simple "said" exclusively has always struck me as odd. A substantial part of the communication between two people is non-verbal and hence simply cannot be conferred by the words alone. Some of it can be inferred for sure, but equally surely not all of it. Maybe that rule has been coined and promoted by language aficionados who think words are everything that is important in the world? Clearly, that is not the case.

As an aside, the "Pete stared" in your example makes me think about one possible solution for the OP's problem: "The old man frowned. 'Right.'" Or maybe he raised an eyebrow.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Also a valid solution.

The way you've written it already seems spot on to me.
It's abundantly clear from context that the old man is being sarcastic here. The preceding dialog makes it obvious that Logan is acting out of character and thus has an ulterior motive for his offer - and that's even without any further context provided by prior setup of Logan's character, which presumably readers would have by this point.
I find it very unlikely that anyone would read the old man's "right" as an indication that Logan's feeble excuse has succeeded in reassuring him, so he now trusts him fully.
If you really wanted to make it abundantly clear that the old man is being sarcastic then replacing "right" with

"Sure" the old man said.

or even

"Hmm, sure" the old man said.

perhaps makes it more obvious.
But I think that's labouring the point somewhat, and I prefer your original way of writing the line.

Describe Actions, Intentions and Body Language
If Logan is up to something, give the reader a hint outside of the dialog. If Logan is sincere and Uncle Graham is being a cranky old jerk... also give the reader a hint outside of the dialog.
Compare the original too:

“I can take him,” a young man interrupted. He stepped out of the shadows, and gave the group a card shark's easy smile. “I can take him there, Uncle Graham, help him find a room.”
Graham eyed him skeptically. “What are you up to this time Logan?”
“Nothing," he said, placing his hand over his heart and giving the wounded look. "I'm just offering to help him find the place.”
“Right," the old man said dryly.

You don't need to replace "said" or alter the spelling of "right" to get across the skepticism. Just give context clues to tell the reader what's going on.
Nearly every line of dialog should have this kind of elaboration; a large fraction of human communication is body language and facial expression.
An additional advantage of this is that you can be less direct in your dialog. "What are you up to this time?" is extremely blunt.
You might try something a little more subtle.

Graham eyed him skeptically. "That's very generous of you, Logan."

The facial expression conveys the idea that Logan is probably working some angle, so the sarcasm and suspicion comes through in the dialog.

You could directly describe the way it was said, eg:

“Right," the old man said, thick with doubt.



"Umph, right..." the old man grunted.

Ellipsis suggests an incomplete train of thought. Preceding with "umph", "uhu" or similar (also suggested by Distopi) emphasizes doubt.  Grunted indicates the old man is a tough nut. Could use "muttered" but this suggests insecurity which might be inconsistent with the character's personality. Similarly adding "under his breath" would indicate doubt.

I like the ellipsis idea. It's like a lingering doubt.
